# Drop all edges on AWS Neptune using pythongremlin

Tags: python, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm using gremlinpython version 3.3.2 and AWS NEPTUNE.
I try to drop all the edges (tried the vertices too) and it fails everytime.
`g.E().drop().iterate()`
Gives me:

> gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 597: Exception
>   processing a script on request [RequestMessage{,
>   requestId=ae49cbb7-e034-4e56-ac76-b62310f753c2, op='bytecode',
>   processor='traversal', args={gremlin=[[], [V(), drop()]],
>   aliases={g=g}}}].

Did anyone already successfuly remove all vertices/edges of a graph in AWS Neptune?

EDIT:
Dropping a specific ID works:
`g.E(id).drop().iterate()`

EDIT2:
Here is a backtrace done using gremlin console:

> gremlin> g.E().count().next()
>
> ==>740839
>   gremlin> g.E().drop().iterate()
>   A timeout occurred within the script during evaluation of [RequestMessage{, requestId=24c3d14c-c8be-4ed9-a297-3fd2b38ace9a, op='eval',   > processor='', args={gremlin=g.E().drop().iterate(), bindings={}, batchSize=64}}] - consider increasing the timeout
>   Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
>   Display stack trace? [yN]y
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.console.RemoteException: A timeout occurred within the script during evaluation of [RequestMessage{,   > requestId=24c3d14c-c8be-4ed9-a297-3fd2b38ace9a, op='eval', processor='', args={gremlin=g.E().drop().iterate(), bindings={},   > batchSize=64}}] - consider increasing the timeout
>     at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.jsr223.DriverRemoteAcceptor.submit(DriverRemoteAcceptor.java:178)
>     at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy:99)
>     at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:122)
>     at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:95)
>     at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
>     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:145)
>     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:165)
>     at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:130)
>     at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:59)
>     at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
>     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:145)
>     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:165)
>     at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:89)
>     at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:236)
>     at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.(Console.groovy:146)
>     at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:236)
>     at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:453)
>   gremlin>

I would say it's a timeout problem, right?

Comment: Not sure why this question is pickup up all the downvotes and a close flag. It's pretty clear if you know gremlinpython, though i don't know why you'd get that specific error for that particular traversal. I don't see anything invalid about it. Did you try to issue the same script from the Gremlin Console to see if that works?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @stephenmallette, I will try to access a Gremlin Console but as it's managed product not sure I can. Keep you in touch

Comment: you can https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-console.html

Comment: I manage to get a backtrace!

Comment: yes - if you are deleting a lot of vertices then you could run into that problem. i'm not sure what the recommended way is to clear a database with neptune. you should check into that - there may be a more efficient approach.

Comment: The proposed version is to use `drop()`, I'm changing the timeout in Neptune configuration system from 2 minutes to 5 minutes. Can you tell me how can I know what error `597` is? (The first error in the question).

Comment: the error 597 is a script exception - as it says in the text of the error. it should be thrown when the Gremlin you send isn't understood by the server, but you look like you have valid Gremlin there, so as I said earlier I'm not sure why Neptune would be rejecting that.

Comment: Even with a 5 minutes timeout it fails to drop. Strange behaviour.

Comment: `g.E().drop()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so after some exchange with @stephen mallette in comment of the question and AWS support I finally found where the problem lies.
As it still a preview NEPTUNE still suffer some smalls issues and `drop()` is one.
A workaround, given by the support is to perform `drop()` in batches via parallel connections:

> g.V().limit(1000).drop()

So dropping table is hitting a timeout right now, even with a 5 minutes timeout and 700.000 edges.
I will update this answer on NEPTUNE's release.

Comment: You shouldn't need the batched delete anymore. g.V().drop().iterate() should work fine now.

Comment: 'shouldn't'  but when:

`gremlin> g.V().drop().iterate()
{"requestId":"50d97889-208b-463f-9c9c-8e89f9df1f65","code":"InternalFailureException","detailedMessage":"An unexpected error has occurred in Neptune."}
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]y
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.console.RemoteException: {"requestId":"50d97889-208b-463f-9c9c-8e89f9df1f65","code":"InternalFailureException","detailedMessage":"An unexpected error has occurred in Neptune."}
 at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.jsr223.DriverRemoteAcceptor.submit(DriverRemoteAcceptor.java:185)`

Comment: batching in groups of 100k seems to work, fine:

`gremlin> g.V().limit(100000).drop().iterate()`